# Import User profile from AD to SharePoin 2013

Tags: import, active-directory-import

I have a question about this import thing, I successfully import the user info in AD to SP2013 using this process [click here](http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/23/setting-user-profile-synchronization-service-in-sharepoint-2013/). But I noticed that it only imports the information on the General tab on AD and not the other tab w/c contains the Mobile No, Pager, etc.

Is there a way to include the other tab information of user on AD to SP2013?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add some **custom property** to the *User Profile*
You can supplement default user profile properties with additional properties to track key information that is not otherwise available.

Take a look at:
[properties in SharePoint Server 2013 user profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262327.aspx)
[SharePoint 2013 user profiles – Add custom properties](http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/224/SharePoint-2013-user-profiles-%E2%80%93-Add-custom-properties)

Comment: Hi @Nk, i followed the steps but when I try to create new property, it shows me an error saying "Sorry, something went wrong." Correlation ID : e067fe9c-7e68-e09e-5164-b1c5d4011ef3

Comment: Pls check the log and post the result

Comment: regarding that problem, its already okay, hehe will update after I finish the steps. Thank you @Nk